# crafting a challenging sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm a newbie in SQL server.

I've the following table:

```
id  dayoftheweek    timeoftheday
1   mondayOpen  0:00 
1   mondayClose 23:59
1   tuesdayOpen 0:00
1   tuesdayClose    23:59
1   wednesdayOpen   0:00
1   wednesdayClose  23:59
1   thursdayOpen    0:00
1   thursdayClose   23:59
1   fridayOpen  0:00
1   fridayClose 23:59
1   saturdayOpen    0:00
1   saturdayClose   23:59
1   sundayOpen  0:00
1   sundayClose 23:59
```

I want the following:

```
     id day     open   close
     1  monday  0:00   23:59
     2  tuesday 0:00   23:59
```

I don't know if i need to write a sproc (T-SQL) or if there are any built-in keywords in SQL , using which i can get the output i desire. I cannot create a new table but views, sprocs are allowed in my existing schema.

Please help me.

TIA

Comment: Every row has `id = 1`? Is there anything that groups the 'monday' rows together, apart from the `dayoftheweek` column containing 'monday'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table structure there is horrid, I'd do anything you could to get away from it.  That said mssql has a few substring functions your can use.

```
select dayoftheweek, timeoftheday 'open'
from uglytable
where right(dayofweek,4) = 'Open'
```

This will give you all records that are open.  We'll do the same thing to get all closed records in a sec.  That will get by the challenge of reading open vs closed

Second issue to address is picking the 'day' column out of that text.  Every day ends in y and contains no other 'y''s in it, so we can use charindex

lil disclaimer...I don't have a mssql db available for testing, so I might be a char off here and there.

```
 select charindex('y',dayoftheweek)
```

That will return the location in the string of the 'y' character.

Mondayopen has a y on the 6th character

```
select left('mondayopen',6)
```

That would return the left 6 chars of mondayOpen or mondayClose.  Put the two together:

```
select left(dayoftheweek,charindex('y',dayoftheweek))
```

Hope I got that right...it should turn mondayopen and mondayclose to monday.  Put the two together:

```
select left(dayoftheweek,charindex('y',dayoftheweek)) dayofweek, timeoftheday 'open'
from uglytable
where right(dayofweek,4) = 'Open'
```

This should now return the dayofweek without the 'open' or 'close' along with the open time.   Turn it into a subquery, join it to the close subquery and put together:

```
select open.dayofweek, open.open,close.close
from
(select left(dayoftheweek,charindex('y',dayoftheweek)) dayofweek, timeoftheday 'open'
from uglytable
where right(dayofweek,4) = 'Open')  open
inner join
(select left(dayoftheweek,charindex('y',dayoftheweek)) dayofweek, timeoftheday 'close'
from uglytable
where right(dayofweek,5) = 'Close')  close
on open.dayofweek = close.dayofweek
```

Hope I don't have syntax errors in there, nothing to test it on and might have a typo ^^

Comment: I probably shouldn't be using a term like open for a table alias should I?

Comment: No, you shouldn't :-) but thanks for the amazing thought of yours. I did put this into production.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is very bad database design. For storing dates you need to use on of [DATE and TIME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) types.

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table(id int,  dayoftheweek varchar(50), timeoftheday varchar(10))
insert into @tbl values (1,   'mondayOpen',  '0:00') 
insert into @tbl values (1,   'mondayClose',  ' 23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'tuesdayOpen',  ' 0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'tuesdayClose',   ' 23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'wednesdayOpen',   '0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'wednesdayClose',  '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'thursdayOpen',   ' 0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'thursdayClose',   '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'fridayOpen',  '0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'fridayClose',  '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'saturdayOpen',   ' 0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'saturdayClose',   '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'sundayOpen',  '0:00')
insert into @tbl values (1,   'sundayClose',  '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'mondayOpen',  '0:00') 
insert into @tbl values (2,   'mondayClose',  ' 23:59')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'tuesdayOpen',  ' 0:00')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'tuesdayClose',   ' 23:59')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'wednesdayOpen',   '0:00')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'wednesdayClose',  '23:59')
insert into @tbl values (2,   'thursdayOpen',   ' 0:00')


SELECT tOpen.id, tOpen.DayOfTheWeek, tOpen.timeoftheday OpenTime, tClose.timeoftheday CloseTime
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(dayoftheweek,'open','') DayOfTheWeek,  timeoftheday,id
      FROM @tbl
      WHERE LEN(REPLACE(dayoftheweek,'open',''))<LEN(dayoftheweek)) tOpen
      JOIN
      (SELECT REPLACE(dayoftheweek,'close','') DayOfTheWeek,  timeoftheday,id
      FROM @tbl
      WHERE LEN(REPLACE(dayoftheweek,'close',''))<LEN(dayoftheweek)) tClose ON tOpen.DayOfTheWeek=tClose.DayOfTheWeek AND tOpen.id=tClose.id
```